# Xamarin.Forms: Why is my <Image/> cut off at two sides, all though there is still room

Tags: xamarin.forms

So this is my whole content page:

```
 <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid Margin="0,-80,0,0">
                <Ellipse
                    Fill="#5abdc1"
                    HeightRequest="60"                   
                    Aspect="Uniform"
                    WidthRequest="60"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Grid.Row="0" />

                <Image Source="img_plus" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="20"/>

                </Grid>

               

                <Image Source="img_menu" HeightRequest="90"/>


                <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <Image Source="img_home_on" Margin="30,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Image Source="img_radar_off" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Image Source="img_radar_off" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <Image Source="img_people_off" Margin="0,0,30,0"  Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="4"/>





                </Grid>


        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
```

The last 4 buttons look like this:

[image]

So, as you can see, the radar image is being cut to the right and at the bottom.

The picture itself ofc is fine.
There is no row spacing or column spacing.
If I put a green background behind the images, I see that there is a lot room still available:

[image]

Can you tell me, why it is behaving like this?

Comment: First step is to find whether that black area is part of the inner grid.  Add a different BackgroundColor to `<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">`. (If the area isn't part of the Grid, then you need to find out what is controlling it.) Second step is to examine your `Margin` properties. If you temporarily REMOVE all Margin statements, or set them to all 0s, what happens? Third step is to consider `Image Aspect`: do you want to use "Fill", even if that stretches/squashes the image?